# How to change thesis template to from A4 to B5?

Tags: margins, thesis

I am using a template for my PhD thesis, but I have a problem with margins. The default is a4paper, but I want put it on b5 size.

```
% Set up the document:
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{Thesis}  % Use the "Thesis" style, based on the ECS Thesis style by Steve Gunn
```

I changed "a4paper" by "b5paper" but it doesn't work. I also changed the margins in the .cls file but it doesn't work either. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

I am using a thesis template downloaded from shareLatex available at: https://es.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/easy-thesis

I tried to print the a4paper and printed in as b5, but i have problems with the resolution of the figures. Thus, I prefer change the size direclty in Latex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. There must be dozens, if not hundreds (or even thousands?) of LaTeX document classes called `Thesis.cls` on the Internet. Which one would you happen to be using? Is it available online? The reason I ask these questions is that an adequate answer to your query will probably depend importantly on the document class you use.

Comment: Welcome, I have bad news for you. The template is very very bad. If you want, you can read a bit [about the history of the tempate](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/ourFamousThesisTemplate.md) (you can also find a link to an improved version there).

Comment: @Johannes_B, I usually save my analysis of "bad" "templates" for Brazilian university templates... I've seen worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the option to the class:

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{Thesis}
```

But be sure to **remove** all these lines from `Thesis.cls`:

```
\PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{\baseclass}

\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb           { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
```

Comment: Usually changing a class file is prohibited for reasons of license and copyright. In this case, you are told to change a copyrighted file. The dirty deed is done already. No harm in creating yet another file that is called `Thesis.cls`. Joseph, it is not your mistake, and it is not your mistake Rose.

Comment: But i would rather drop that template and start with a [minimal template](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports).

Comment: @Johannes_B, I agree, I'd rather drop that template, too... but since the user asked, I presumed he "had" to use it, for some reason... None of the `.cls` files claimed any copyright, so I didn't bother looking around.

Comment: Sunil removed the copyright note. :-(